# How to install XCode 9 GM on MacOS Sierra 10.12?

Tags: xcode9

I actually built a Hackintosh to learn programming with Xcode. It runs on my Asus X555LA laptop. I downloaded the latest Xcode 9 GM build from the Apple Site (not from App store). After extracting, when I tried to install, it shows "You can't use this version of the application "Xcode" with this version of macOS; You have macOS 10.12. The application requires macOS 10.12.6 or later".

Is there any tweak to make it run on my Sierra 10.12 itself? I can't really think about upgrading the macOS version as it's a Hackintosh. I followed [this guide](https://www.techbii.com/install-macos-sierra-laptop-hackintosh/) to install macOS on my Asus laptop.

Comment: Is it code related problem!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode requires latest macOS, you have no choice, you need to upgrade the macOS version on your Hackintosh. Or better: Reinstall macOS in a recommended way on your PC, if you're doing Hackintosh... :)

The guide you linked is very poor... Never use premade install images, because these have been modified in an uncertain way, and you don't want to install a premade undocumented mess to your computer. It might be packed with threats, malwares, spy tools and so on.. It's the worst thing I can imagine in security aspect to install an OS image from uncertain source.
Also, there is no universal macOS installer for PCs - even though many are trying to find a way to create it: it's a bad idea and it will never succeed because there are so many PC parts, millions of differently built computers..

The only way to create a stable fully functional Hackintosh is to know your hardware and create an installer flash drive for that specific PC. First you have to download the latest macOS Sierra from AppStore, this is the only source that you can trust, because it's downloading from Apple's servers. Then install a small program, called Clover bootloader to the flash drive to make it bootable.

[This is the only full and up to date guide for PC laptops](https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/guide-booting-the-os-x-installer-on-laptops-with-clover.148093/). If you have questions, register to the linked site and start a new forum thread posting your questions. They will help you but please read this guide at least 3-4 times carefully because everything is described here.